# Use HtmlUnit as crawler

Tags: java, web-crawler, htmlunit

I needed a headless browser to parse pages.
HtmlUnit allow me to setup a Heroku Java app to fullfil this purpose.

But now I'm meeting with couple of issues.

The current one is malformed url "//path" instead of "/path" or "http(s)://path".
I downloaded sources of the 2.9.4 version and pushed tiny fixes in the sources ...
It's not really efficient to modify standard sources for obvious maintainability reasons.

I'm so wondering if i'm not digging in the wrong direction.
HtmlUnit is designed to browse pages in a testing purpose. Mine is to do like a browser, so make page working the most possible, especially because my damned targeted websites are the kind of ultra-dirty-not-respecting-anything...

What is your opinion about this retrospection ?

Comment: The other solutions I was thinking about are :
Saucelabs.com with Selenium on rails, but I'm stuck with downloading files http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980155/how-to-download-attachment-with-ruby-and-selenium except that it works totaly.
Another idea is to use a nodeJS app with ZombieJS. The idea was to have a real DOM + JS environement but my first tests are already raising lot's of JS errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML Unit is used in [Selenium 2/Web Driver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html) for headless browser "simulation". There it works fine.

So I see no reason not to try Html Unit. May you can have a look at [Selenium 2/Web Driver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html) too.